Actively engaging psychology departments on Facebook?
For some months now we have a magnificent Facebook page on which questions are posted on a weekly basis, with a short accompanying text. However, we are having some troubles getting an audience (we only have 19 page likes, i.e. subscribers, today (26-10-2016)). We are currently testing different moments in time to see when the reach of our posts is the largest. 
Another neat possibility on Facebook is for pages to like other pages. If a page (Page 1) likes another page (Page 2), then Page 1 posts a message on their timeline showing they like Page 2, thereby promoting Page 2. There are many university psychology departments, that have a Facebook page. These are followed, not only by (PhD-)students, but also PhDs, professors, and former students that are currently working in the field. If psychology departments would like our pages, then thousands of people (which are our target audience) will get to know of our existence. Therefore, I was thinking to send a message to the psychology departments, asking them to like us. 
What are your thoughts about actively engaging the psychology departments of different universities? And how should we go about? 

If you agree with an active approach, it may be a good idea to include a prototypical message in which we can clearly and briefly tell about what CogSci.SE is and what our intentions are. 
If you do not agree with this approach, do you have any alternative approaches that may increase our visibility on Facebook?

Hmm, I would hold back with thus until we have a more professional appearance on this site: i.e., the upcoming negotiations.

Psychology departments use Facebook? Interesting...
